# Mysql array, регуляроное выражение

Tags: php, mysql, symfony3, doctrine2

В базе данных Mysql есть поле "другие категории" по которому нужно сделать выборку

Сейчас это делается так (так не работает)

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("
                SELECT p
                FROM AppBundle:Product p
                where p.category=".$category->getId()." or p.otherCategories LIKE '/^i:[0-9];%i:".$category->getId().";%/'             
                order by p.vt ASC");
```

в поле otherCategories данные хранятся в виде массива

```
a:3:{i:0;i:10;i:1;i:12;i:2;i:32;} где i:0;i:10 0 - номер, 10 значение
```

мне для выборки нужно составить примерно такую регулярку i:[любая цифра, от 1 до 10-ти];i:[передаваемый параметр];

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать регулярку или может быть обойтись без неё -- возможно есть какие-то другие функции в этом плане.

Comment: Не делайте так, это очень медленно, и как только размер таблицы будет хоть сколько нибудь значимым всё начнет тормозить... Делайте нормальную связь многие ко многим, с помощью дополнительной таблицы.

Comment: Нормализуйте данные. Заодно и запрос станет элементарным. *любая цифра, от 1 до 10* Надеюсь, Вы в курсе, что 10 - это не цифра... а также надеюсь, что "номера"-таки от 0 до 9... тогда рег будет `"'%i:\d;i:".$category->getId().";%'"`